# Why variable of long type is giving different answer after casting and before casting in the following code as both are of type long?

Tags: java, casting

```
byte byteChallenge = 68;
short shortChallenge = 190;
int intChallenge = 2147483647;

long longChallenge = (50000L + 10L * (byteChallenge + shortChallenge + intChallenge));

long longChallengeX = 50000L + 10L * ((long) byteChallenge + (long) shortChallenge + (long) 
                          intChallenge);

System.out.println(longChallenge);
System.out.println(longChallengeX);
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
-21474783910
21474889050
```

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer by clicking on the corresponding checkmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part is `int intChallenge = 2147483647` constant which is the maximum value for positive `int` (see `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

When you perform `byteChallenge + shortChallenge + intChallenge` it is an `int` arithmetic statement which results in [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). In your example the integer overflow result is a negative number.

When you perform `(long) byteChallenge + (long) shortChallenge + (long) intChallenge` it is `long` arithmetic. Since `long` supports much larger values than `int` there is no overflow.

Answer (score 1):

In the first scenario, the sub-expression `(byteChallenge + shortChallenge + intChallenge)` is basically "`byte + short + int`". Java evaluates this part first, before multiplying by 10 and adding to 50000.

Since the sub-expression doesn't involve a `long` type, Java has no reason to make the result type of the expression `long`, so the first two operands is only promoted to `int` and the three `int`s are added together to give another `int`. This causes an overflow, making the result very negative.

In the second case, you explicitly cast all three operands to `long` before operating on them, so the type of the sub-expression is resolved to be `long`.

The lesson here is that nested expressions are treated the same as any other expressions. `(byteChallenge + shortChallenge + intChallenge)` doesn't get special treatment just because it is multiplied with a `long`. Its value is still evaluated the same way.